# I want to use a local variable outside of functions

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and Im trying to create a program that will ask the user to select an image file using `tk.filedialog` and then do some `PIL` related work on it.. 'cause i've made a button that `on-press` will execute a function (`Button = tk.Button(win, text="Select File", command=buttonFunc`)), and the `command` parameter only takes a function name, I defined a function to open up the dialog and let user select the file, I wanted my function to store the path of the selected file, (In this case, in the variable *path*), It saves the path in the local variable but I wanna use it outside of function as well,, I've used `global` statement to make the variable global but it doesn't seem to work..

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import os
from tkinter import INSERT
from tkinter import TOP
from tkinter import LEFT
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance
import time

# Main Screen
win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Color Enhancer')
win.geometry('500x70')
# Below line of code is used to set window icon, Not really sure how it works, copied from Net and pasted here.
win.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', win._w, tk.PhotoImage(file='icon.gif'))
Lab = tk.Label(win, text='Welcome to Color Enhancer, This mini utility is written purely in \n'
                         'Python and can be used to change colors of given Image, Select \n'
                         ' image and see the magic.')
Lab.pack()


def buttonFunc():
    global path
    path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    print(path)
# buttonFunc() --> Works fine if i call it here, But it opens the dialog before even the button appears..


button = tk.Button(win, text='Select File', command=buttonFunc)
button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
print(path)
win.mainloop()
```

I've tried to run the code and it throws the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iMacPro 2K19\Desktop\Main\Python\Scratches\PIL_Edit.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(path)
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

I know that it is saying that the *path* is not defined.. but as You can see that I've defined it and also made it global..
One thing i wanna say that if I call `buttonFunc()` after defining it.. It works.. But it opens up the dialog before i press the button.. Is there any other way to solve it, or someone please tell me where im going wrong..

Comment: Have you tried initializing the path variable outside the function like this: path='' ?

Comment: What do you expect to see with the `print(path)` statement before `win.mainloop()` in your code?  Because even though you have initialized the `path` variable, the path is meaningless at the moment you print it.

Answer (score 0):

`path` is only defined inside the function `buttonFunc()`. That's fine. But it also means that the variable `path` is UNDEFINED until the `buttonFunc()` func is called to initialize it.

Because your code only calls that func when the button is pressed, the `path` variable is still undefined when you hit your `print(path)` statement, because the button has not yet been hit to call the func to init the variable.

You can either initialize the `path` variable before the `print(path)` call, or you can just remove that `print(path)` call from there because it does not really do anything, and you can leave it inside your function, as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the path variable outside the function. Only then you will be able to access it globally.

```
path=None 
def buttonFunc():
    global path
    path="file path"
buttonFunc()
print(path)
```

Comment: The `path` inside `buffonFunc()` is a local variable without declaring `global path` inside the function.  So it won't change the global `path` variable.

Comment: @acw1668 i got that, see the updated answer. It works fine.